# Pods getting OOMKilled even though process memory is within Memory limits

Tags: out-of-memory, amazon-eks, cgroups

Memory limit is configured as 4GB. K8S - 1.24

anon-rss is 2333732kB which is around 2.3 GB.

```
Memory cgroup out of memory: Killed process 32247 (java) total-vm:21500696kB, anon-rss:2333732kB, file-rss:26248kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:0 pgtables:34060kB oom_score_adj:935`
```

```
[5189822.576224] R13: 00007fc5b7e95fa4 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 00007fc7ad671000
[5189822.584504] memory: usage 4177300kB, limit 4194304kB, failcnt 7408
[5189822.589753] memory+swap: usage 4177272kB, limit 9007199254740988kB, failcnt 0
[5189822.596872] kmem: usage 531332kB, limit 9007199254740988kB, failcnt 0
[5189822.601647] Memory cgroup stats for /kubepods.slice/kubepods-burstable.slice/kubepods-burstable-pode7e7f5f2_087c_44c7_b402_5187553ec344.slice:
[5189822.601662] anon 3733340160
[5189822.601662] file 135168
[5189822.601662] kernel_stack 234897408
[5189822.601662] percpu 0
[5189822.601662] sock 0
[5189822.601662] shmem 0
[5189822.601662] file_mapped 135168
[5189822.601662] file_dirty 0
[5189822.601662] file_writeback 0
[5189822.601662] anon_thp 0
[5189822.601662] inactive_anon 3733340160
[5189822.601662] active_anon 0
[5189822.601662] inactive_file 24576
[5189822.601662] active_file 0
[5189822.601662] unevictable 0
[5189822.601662] slab_reclaimable 15090608
[5189822.601662] slab_unreclaimable 200927056
[5189822.601662] slab 216017664
[5189822.601662] workingset_refault_anon 0
[5189822.601662] workingset_refault_file 4841
[5189822.601662] workingset_activate_anon 0
[5189822.601662] workingset_activate_file 660
[5189822.601662] workingset_restore_anon 0
[5189822.601662] workingset_restore_file 12
[5189822.601662] workingset_nodereclaim 0
[5189822.601662] pgfault 7569717
[5189822.698701] Tasks state (memory values in pages):
[5189822.702734] [  pid  ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
[5189822.710127] [  28270] 65535 28270      243        1    28672        0          -998 pause
[5189822.719271] [  32247]     0 32247  5375174   589966 34877440        0           935 java
[5189822.726548] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_MEMCG,nodemask=(null),cpuset=cri-containerd-c3f27b10c8927be9d8eea662b968506168a40310d8d313cb213288def72f6f01.scope,mems_allowed=0,oom_memcg=/kubepods.slice/kubepods-burstable.slice/kubepods-burstable-pode7e7f5f2_087c_44c7_b402_5187553ec344.slice,task_memcg=/kubepods.slice/kubepods-burstable.slice/kubepods-burstable-pode7e7f5f2_087c_44c7_b402_5187553ec344.slice/cri-containerd-c3f27b10c8927be9d8eea662b968506168a40310d8d313cb213288def72f6f01.scope,task=java,pid=32247,uid=0
[5189822.775355] Memory cgroup out of memory: Killed process 32247 (java) total-vm:21500696kB, anon-rss:2333732kB, file-rss:26248kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:0 pgtables:34060kB oom_score_adj:935
```

This is happening across lot of pods...when we try stress test on these pods, then it get OOMKilled around 4GB.